# Automatically Resize UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uicollectionview

In Xcode 6 Beta 5, I had a chat interface that looks like the iOS 7 messages app, where the UILabel that the text was inside sized to the width of the text itself. When I updated to Beta 6, I noticed an option for UILabel in interface builder that I hadn't noticed before:

[image]

When I have the explicit width set, the width doesn't change at all based on the width of the text. When I uncheck explicit, the width of the text is at least 234, so it expands out of the view.

I am using a UICollectionView inside of a UIViewController, and here is my cell for item at index path method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let row = indexPath.row

    var cell: UICollectionViewCell

    let path = UIBezierPath()

    let object: AnyObject = (messages[row] as NSDictionary).objectForKey("user_id")!
    let uid: AnyObject = defaults.objectForKey("user_id")!

    if "\(object)" == "\(uid)" {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(right_chat_bubble, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

        path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 10))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(12, 5))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))
    }
    else {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(left_chat_bubble, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

        path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 5))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(12, 10))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(12, 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 5))
    }

    let initial_view = cell.viewWithTag(101) as UILabel
    initial_view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    initial_view.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let name = (messages[row] as NSDictionary).objectForKey("name")! as String
    let name_array = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    let first_initial = name_array[0]
    let last_initial = name_array[1]

    let first_char = first_initial[0]
    let last_char = last_initial[0]
    let initials = first_char + last_char

    initial_view.text = initials

    let circle: UIView = cell.viewWithTag(103)! as UIView

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.frame = circle.bounds
    mask.path = path.CGPath

    circle.layer.mask = mask

    let message = cell.viewWithTag(102) as ChatLabel
    message.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link.toRaw()
    message.delegate = self
    message.text = (messages[row] as NSDictionary).objectForKey("content")! as String
    message.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    message.layer.masksToBounds = true

    message.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at sizeThatFits: and sizeToFit:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeThatFits:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit

A UILabel can call sizeThatFits like :

```
myLabelLbl.text = @"some text"
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(200, 800)
CGSize expectedSize = [myLabelLbl sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize]
myLabelLbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, expectedSize.width, expectedSize.height) //set the new size
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The way I have my cell set up is with constraints on the top and bottom of the UILabel to the top and bottom of the cell, and I calculate the cell height using sizeThatFits, and that works perfectly. Unless there is a way to have a UIContainerViewCell not centered, I have to directly change the size of the label using those methods. I've tried both of those methods and neither of them work as expected. Its hit or miss whether the label will resize, and as I scroll and cells reload, they change widths and go off the screen.